# Better way to assign variables?

Tags: jquery, variables, for-loop

In my project, I have 20-30 user input values that are assigned to variables. Each input has an id that I have tried to structure in a smart way. But I'm new to coding so I have been writing out each variable assignment in order. This is not a neat way to do it, but I'm not sure how to structure a for loop to fit the bill.

My vars are structured as such:

```
    var box_1 = $("#box1").val();
    var box_1_2 = $("#box1_2").val();
    var box_2 = $("#box2").val();
    var box_2_2 = $("#box2_2").val();
    var box_3 = $("#box3").val();
    var box_4 = $("#box4").val();
    var box_4_2 = $("#box4_2").val();
    var box_5 = $("#box5").val();
    var box_5_2 = $("#box5_2").val();
    var box_6 = $("#box6").val();
    var box_7 = $("#box7").val();
    var box_8 = $("#box8").val();
    var box_9 = $("#box9").val();
    var box_9_2 = $("#box9_2").val();
    var box_9_3 = $("#box9_3").val();
    var box_9_4 = $("#box9_4").val();
    etc...
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

**EDITED TO ADDRESS SOME COMMENTS**

To answer the question in the comment:
The ids are randomly named boxn and variables box_n, for ease of writing.
 
The ids refer to a mixture of selectboxes, input fields and radio buttons.
Every box_n is always assigned to boxn.
Some boxn will be followed by boxn_a, boxn_b, boxn_c because these are part of related input fields.

Now why this? The end user moves through each field, changes the options or enters text to suit their need, and the end result is text generated using the vars. Kind of like a mad lib generator.

Comment: Okay, we know you have a lot of textboxes, but what for? What is the structure of this input? Is every `boxn_n` related to `boxn`? How? Why are there different numbers? Does the number vary (a list of lists, perhaps?), or are these fixed fields that should actually have names?

Comment: _"I have 20-30 user inputs that are assigned to variables"_ - No, the _values_ of the inputs are assigned to variables. If you showed (a sample of) your html and the desired output we could give you advice on how to achieve it. E.g., if the output text you are generating is made up exclusively of values from the various fields you could probably structure things such that you could loop through every field without needing to know the ids and without the variables.

Comment: @nnnnnn: The majority of the text generated is derived from the input values. But, some fields are not visible to the user unless certain select options are made or radio buttons checked. I already have a working product that does what I want - but, as new versions are made, I find that my list of variables keeps growing. The text generation is pretty stable. I have been having problems trying to make for loops to grab and assign the values no matter how many fields I add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**

You could use multidimensional arrays [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TTXKm/)

```
var box_counts = [2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4];
var box_vars = [];

for (var i = 0; i < box_counts.length; i++) {
    box_vars[i] = [];
    box_vars[i][0] = $('#box' + (i + 1)).val();
    for (var j = 1; j < box_counts[i]; j++) {
        box_vars[i][j] = $('#box' + (i + 1) + '_' + (j + 1)).val();
    }
}
```

Example use: `box_vars[0][1]` refers to the value of your current `box_1_2` variable, `box_vars[8][3]` refers to your `box_9_4` variable. Note that since the arrays are 0 indexed while you are using 1 indexed names you will have to do a bit of mental arithmetic or change the structure to have an empty 0 index

**Method 2**

Alternatively you can make the variables window attributes [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQjAy/2/)

```
$('[id^=box]').each(function(){
    window[this.id.replace('box', 'box_')] = $(this).val()
})
```

which would allow you to call them how you do now. They will be global however.

Example use: `box_1_2` will refer to `$("#box1_2").val();` and `box_9_4` will refer to `$("#box9_4").val();` like you would expect with your current system

Comment: Your second method seems to work well - except for one thing. One page load, all the variables are assigned dynamically, as expected. However, the variable values are not updated when any change event occurs (either select box change or text input). is there a way to update the variable values on any change?